# How to make a dotted border style in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the border style of my form using Windows Forms. The problem is I'm stuck and don't know where to go. As for now the `FormBorderStyle` is set to `none`. The hint I got is that I have to use `Pen.DashStyle`. Here is a screenshot of what I need.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to be looking at the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) Event of your `Form` and the [`Graphics.DrawRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle.aspx) Method of the PaintEventArgs.